# SymPy - Generates huge equation while inverse laplace transform

Tags: python, transform, sympy, inverse

When I do a really simple inverse laplace transform with Sympy, I got a huge equation back.

For example:

```
from sympy import *
s = symbols ('s')
t = symbols ('t', positive=True) # Just to remove the Heaviside(t) equations
k, m = symbols ('k m', const=True) 
A = Matrix([[0, 1], [-k/m, 0]])
I = eye(2) # Diagonalmatrix 
Fi = inverse_laplace_transform((s*I-A).inv(), s,  t)
print(pretty(simplify(Fi)))
```

Now a get an enormous huge equation from `Fi`. Why? Is something wrong with `inverse_laplace_transform()` function from Sympy?

Comment: try `k, m = symbols ('k m', positive=True)`

Comment: That was mutch better. Thank you. Now it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inverse lapace transform is used to turn transfer functiuons into discrete form instead of time continuous.

Instead of using inverse laplace transform, we can use this code instead, where `h` is the sample time. Image that we have a transfer function G(s), and you want to find the discrete equivalent model of G(s). Find the state space model of G(s) and then run this Octave/MATLAB code:

```
% Compute sizes
a1 = size(A,2) + size(B,2) - size(A,1);
b1 = size(A,2);
a2 = size(A,2) + size(B,2) - size(B,1);
b2 = size(B,2);
% Compute square matrix
M = [A B; zeros(a1, b1)  zeros(a2, b2)];
M = expm(M*h);
 % Find the discrete matrecies
Ad = M(1:size(A,1), 1:size(A,2));
Bd = M(1:size(B,1), (size(A,2) + 1):(size(A,2) + size(B,2)));
```

Code source: https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Matavecontrol/blob/master/sourcecode/c2d.m